# Use blackberry camera in java app to select a photo that was already on file

Tags: java, blackberry, camera, invoke

I know you can use

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_CAMERA, null);
```

to get the blackberry camera application to be shown and allow the user to take photos. From which you can use a FileJournalListener to find any created files.
(As shown/implied in this forum post: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-FileJournalListener/td-p/295424)

There are times however, when the user chooses not to take a photo but selects one from the file system.  Since this wasn't created at the time I opened it, using the FileJournalListener is not going to meet my needs.

What should I use to get the selected file?

EDIT: The functionality I'm trying to produce I've seen in the Twitter for blackberry application

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a file picker first,

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_file_picker_856986_11.jsp

After that in the application, user could select whether to capture new picture or browse from their storage.
If user select the later, open up this file picker and for every images found user can view the image, and the application can save the path where the images located for further processing.

Comment: Since the camera application has a built-in file-picker, I really want to explore using it as is provided.  If I have to, I'll use this, so thanks for the idea.